# How to combine exchange-to-exchange bindings and federation in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a design for a RabbitMQ topology, but recently learned that RabbitMQ federation ignores messages that aren't "directly published" to the upstream exchange.  This is a problem, because I am using a combination of exchange-to-exchange bindings and federation, so my setup isn't working.

Essentially, our setup is to have messages flowing into one exchange on an "inbound" server, federated to an exchange on a "routing" server, which is bound to another exchange on a routing server, which is federated to an "outgoing" server (which is where clients create queues and bind them).  The reasoning behind the exchange-to-exchange binding is to force the routing to happen there, instead of allowing it to happen all the way upstream as would occur without that link.  For load reasons, we can't afford for the routing to happen upstream in the "inbound" servers.

Is there a way to re-publish messages in the routing server so federation picks them up, or something to that effect?  Is there something other than federation I should use in this topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [shovel plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) allows you to do just that.  It consumes from one exchange and re-publishes to another, and the exchanges can be on the same or different nodes.